# Update Current Table with Staging Table in SQL based on unique identifier

Tags: sql, join, select, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I have a main table

```
id date           in_US?
1  '2020-06-15'   FALSE
2  '2020-06-20'   TRUE
3  '2020-06-22'   FALSE
4  '2020-06-25'   TRUE
```

and then an update table

```
id date           in_US?
1  '2020-06-15'   TRUE
2  '2020-06-20'   FALSE
```

How do I write an update statement that updates the main table with the rows in the update table based on the unique identifier (id)?

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift, you would use the `update ... set ... from ... where` syntax, like so:

```
update main_table
set in_us = u.in_us, date = u.date
from update_table u
where main_table.id = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
update maintable m
    set in_us = u.is_us
    from updatetable u
    where m.id = u.id;
```

I don't know if you want to consider the date as well.  If so, that would also go in the `where` clause.